# Unknown column '' in 'field list' mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a SQL project, and I got some problem, it said "`#1054 - Unknown column 'b.idleaderboard' in 'field list'`.

This code was perfectly fine on localhost, but when i'm uploading the code to phpmyadmin, an error appears.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT b.idleaderboard, 
       b.id_regist, 
       b.nama_band, 
       b.personil, 
       a.title_vids, 
       a.likes_vids 
FROM   tb_leaderboard b 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   videos) a 
              ON b.id_regist = a.id_regist 
GROUP  BY b.id_regist, 
          b.nama_band 
ORDER  BY likes_vids DESC
```

Why isn't it working when I'm uploading that code to phpmyadmin hosting?
thankyou guys

Comment: Please provide your `tb_leaderboard` table structure

Comment: It may be a lowecase/uppercase problem. Please show your table structure or create a sqlfiddle to demonstrate the problem!